# prolog negation \+

Tags: prolog, negation

There are four baskets, and each with a unique color. I write a prolog program to tell the color oder based on some facts and rules. This is the .pl file:

```
iright(L, R, [L | [R | _]]).
iright(L, R, [_ | Rest]) :- iright(L, R, Rest).
nextto(L, R, List) :- iright(L, R, List).
nextto(L, R, List) :- iright(R, L, List).

myprogram(Data) :-     =(Data, [_,red,_,_]), 
\+nextto(red,blue,Data), % blue is not next to red
iright(red,green,Data), %green is right to red
member(red,Data),
member(blue,Data),
member(green,Data),
member(yellow,Data).
```

The iright and nextto predicates are correct. My query is `myprogram(Data)`, and I expect the result should be

```
Data = [yellow,red, green, blue]?
yes
```

but actually the prompt show that

```
| ?- myprogram(Data).

no
```

I know the problem is the negation, but idk how and why. Plz help.

When I use `trace.`

```
      1    1  Call: myprogram(_16) ? 
      2    2  Call: \+nextto(red,blue,[_46,red,_50,_52]) ? 
      3    3  Call: nextto(red,blue,[_46,red,_50,_52]) ? 
      4    4  Call: iright(red,blue,[_46,red,_50,_52]) ? 
      5    5  Call: iright(red,blue,[red,_50,_52]) ? 
      5    5  Exit: iright(red,blue,[red,blue,_52]) ? 
      4    4  Exit: iright(red,blue,[_46,red,blue,_52]) ? 
      3    3  Exit: nextto(red,blue,[_46,red,blue,_52]) ? 
      2    2  Fail: \+nextto(red,blue,[_46,red,_50,_52]) ? 
      1    1  Fail: myprogram(_16) ? 

(2 ms) no
```

Comment: Have you tried tracing the execution? Type `trace.` at the Prolog prompt.

Comment: I've posted it, plz take a look.

Comment: I think you just stumbled upon a case of floundering.
If you want to know more try googling "sldnf floundering".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the `\+nextto(red, blue, Data)` to the last line of `myprogram`, it works.

It's a little unintuitive but you need to think a bit about how Prolog evaluates expressions & what negation really means.  Negation means "there's no possible way for this to be true", not "can't be true for a particular set of values".  If you strip your program down to simply:

```
 myprogram(Data) :-
    =(Data, [_,red,_,_]),
    \+nextto(red,blue,Data).
```

You will still get a `No.`.  This is because, with what you've declared, Data **can be** `[_, red, blue, _]` - you see this decision made at `Exit: iright(red,blue,[red,blue,_52])`.  Prolog tries to backtrack, but there's nothing else it can try - you haven't constrained any of the _s to have a particular value yet.

If, OTOH, you put all your nextto, member & iright statements before your negated statement, there's multiple possible solutions (well, two) to try when it gets to the negated expression: `Data = [blue,red,green,yellow]` and `Data = [yellow,red,green,blue]`.  At this point, when it sees the negation it 'throws away' the 'branch' where red is next to blue, but it's able to backtrack and has a possible world state that makes the negation true. That is to say that:

```
myprogram(Data) :-
    =(Data, [_,red,_,_]),
    iright(red,green,Data),
    member(red,Data),
    member(blue,Data),
    member(green,Data),
    member(yellow,Data),
    \+nextto(red,blue,Data).
```

...gives you the desired results.

*TL;DR* - negation (and cuts, when you get to them) in Prolog are a lot more powerful than you think at first.  Make sure you've figured everything else out first before using them.

Comment: "there's no possible way for this to be true" isn't what Prolog's negation means. Rather, it means "can't be proven with the current information according to our limited inference algorithm", which is why you get hickups like `\+ member(X, [1,2,3]), X=4`.